# Expose Google Endpoint API on ingress

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-health-check

I have an API on google Endpoint, the backend is deployed on GKE and I'd like to expose it via an ingress so I can use IAP on it.
I am using ESP2.
I first deploy my service as a LoadBalancer and it was working.

Thing is my ingress says:
"All backend services are in UNHEALTHY state "
I get that the health check does not pass but I do not get why...

The service and the pod corresponding show no error, however on my pod event I can see:
" Readiness probe failed: Get http://10.32.1.27:8000/swagger: dial tcp 10.32.1.27:8000: connect: connection refused "

my configurations for pod and service looks like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
 name: devfleet-django-endpoint-service
 namespace: my-ns
spec:
  # NodePort is mandatory for Ingress to perform load balancer
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 9000
    name: https
  selector:
    app: devfleet-django-endpoint
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: devfleet-django-endpoint
  namespace: my-ns
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: devfleet-django-endpoint
   template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: devfleet-django-endpoint
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: esp
        image: gcr.io/endpoints-release/endpoints-runtime:2
        args: [
          "--listener_port=9000",
          "--backend", "127.0.0.1:8080",
          "--service=my-custom-domain.io",
          "--rollout_strategy=managed",
          "-z", "healthz",
          "--ssl_server_cert_path", "/etc/esp/ssl"
        ]
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /etc/esp/ssl
          name: esp-ssl
          readOnly: true
        - mountPath: /etc/nginx/custom
          name: nginx-config
          readOnly: true        
        ports:
          - containerPort: 9000
      - name: devfleet-django-endpoint
        image: my-img
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8000
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        env:
         some_env_data
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /swagger
            port: 8000
          initialDelaySeconds: 10
          periodSeconds: 10
          timeoutSeconds: 10
          failureThreshold: 3
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
           path: /swagger
            port: 8000
          initialDelaySeconds: 15
          periodSeconds: 60
          timeoutSeconds: 10
          failureThreshold: 3
        volumeMounts:
          - name: devfleet-storage
            mountPath: /secrets/cloudstorage
            readOnly: true
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 30m
            memory: 90Mi
          limits:
            cpu: 200m
            memory: 400Mi            
      - image: b.gcr.io/cloudsql-docker/gce-proxy:1.13
        name: cloudsql-proxy
        command: ["/cloud_sql_proxy", "--dir=/app",
                  "-instances=production-213911:europe-west1:dev-postgresql=tcp:5432",
                  "-credential_file=/secrets/cloudsql/credentials.json"]
        volumeMounts:
           - name: prodsql-oauth-credentials
            mountPath: /secrets/cloudsql
            readOnly: true
         resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 10m
            memory: 10Mi
          limits:
            cpu: 20m
            memory: 50Mi          
      volumes:
        - name: prodsql-oauth-credentials
          secret:
            secretName: secret-name
        - name: devfleet-storage
           secret:
            secretName: secret-name
        - name: app
           emptyDir:
        - name: esp-ssl
          secret:
            secretName: secret-name
        - name: nginx-config
          configMap:
            name: nginx-config
          
      nodeSelector:
        cloud.google.com/gke-nodepool: default-pool
```

and my ingress configuration is:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: devapi
  namespace: my-ns
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: ingress-devapi
    ingress.gcp.kubernetes.io/pre-shared-cert: "my-cert"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: gce
    ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "false"
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: devfleet-django-endpoint-service
    servicePort: 443
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong ?
Thank you

Comment: Did you check ingress controller logs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in order to expose your API deploy on google endpoint on an ingress with the esp container and your app container in the same pod you will need to create Backend config with specific health check.

Here is what I did:

1. Added Backend config:

> ```
> apiVersion: cloud.google.com/v1  
> kind: BackendConfig  
> metadata:  
>    name: esp-config  
>   namespace: my-namespace  
> spec:  
>   healthCheck:  
>     checkIntervalSec: 80  
>     port: the-node-port-on-which-your-service-is-exposed  
>     type: HTTPS  
>     requestPath: /healthz
> ```

```
apiVersion: cloud.google.com/v1
kind: BackendConfig
metadata:
  name: devapi-config
  namespace: my-namespace
spec:
  healthCheck:
    checkIntervalSec: 80
    port: the-node-port-on-which-your-service-is-exposed
    requestPath: /
```

2. Update my service:

> ```
> apiVersion: v1
> kind: Service
> metadata:
>   name: name
>   namespace: my-namespace
>   annotations:
>     cloud.google.com/backend-config: '{"ports": {
>     "443":"esp-config",
>     "8035":"devapi-config"
>     }}'
>
> spec:
>   ports:
>   - port: Exposed port
>     targetPort: target-port-you-set-in-deployment
>     protocol: TCP
>     name: name
>   - port: Exposed port
>     targetPort: target-port-you-set-in-deployment
>     protocol: TCP
>     name: another-name
>   selector:
>     app: name
>   type: NodePort
> ```

3. Update my ingress

> ```
> apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
> kind: Ingress
> metadata:
>   name: name
>   namespace: my-namespace
>   annotations:
>     kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: static-ip-name
>     ingress.gcp.kubernetes.io/pre-shared-cert: my-cert
>     kubernetes.io/ingress.class: gce
>     ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"
>
> spec:
>   backend:
>     serviceName: my-service-name
>     servicePort: The-exposed-port-of-my-application (not esp)
> ```